# Wrong encoding for partial

Tags: compass-sass, sass

I am running `compass watch my_project` on Windows XP.

- `index.scss`:

  ```
  @charset "UTF-8";
  @import 'partial';
  // ...
  ```
- `_partial.scss`:

  ```
  p:before {
      content: '•';
  }
  ```
- `config.rb`:

  ```
  encoding = "utf-8"
  ```
- Generated `index.css`:

  ```
  @charset "UTF-8";
  /* line 1, ../sass/_partial.scss */
  p:before {
    content: 'ÔÇó';
  }
  // ...
  ```

How do I make Compass/Sass interpret the partial as UTF-8? Is there
perhaps an environment variable that I can set to change default
character encoding used by Ruby (`compass` is a Ruby app)?

Comment: Is the file actually using UTF-8 encoding? What version of Ruby?

Comment: EMACS's `describe-coding-system` says: `Coding system for saving this buffer: U -- utf-8-dos (alias: mule-utf-8-dos)` Ruby version: `ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25) [i386-mingw32]`

Answer (score 5):

On my Windows 7 machine, it worked to add the following line to my project's `config.rb`

```
Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8'
```

Also found a great GUI for compass / less / JS compression: http://koala-app.com/

Comment: Two additions: (a) `output_style = :compressed` adds a UTF-8 BOM [by design](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1449#issuecomment-57013728); and (b) within a Docker environment, changes to config.rb are only applied after a Docker restart.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is not a direct answer, but even if you can't make Compass/Sass interpret UTF as you want, you may simply try to use unicode escape:

```
p:before {
    content: "\2022";
}
```

Where 2022 is hexadecimal code for your symbol. To get this code I executed this in irb:

```
irb> "•"[0].ord.to_s(16)
=> "2022"
```

Probably not a good solution if you have a lot of unicode chars, but at least a workaround. For example, [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) uses it in its [stylesheets](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/sass/font-awesome.sass).

Comment: This works beautifully, and it solves the problem for me! Still, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Using `content: "\2022"` is the correct approach for delivering unicode characters via CSS.

Comment: To clarify: Putting UTF-8 encoded Unicode characters in CSS is perfectly fine. Using `content: "\2022"` may be more comfortable, though — less worries about encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from escaping the character (predictable, but tedious) as suggested by @NIA, there are  two other ways around this:

1. Add `@charset "utf-8";` to the top of _partial.scss
2. Save _partial.scss as "UTF-8 with BOM".

Judging by what I've read so far, this seems to be a generic Ruby/WIN issue with incorrect encoding detection/fallback when building strings read from files on disk.