# @import line expected selector or at-rule, but not because of missing semicolon

Tags: compass-sass

I have this compass error

```
Line 3: Invalid CSS after "@charset "UTF-8"": expected selector or at-rule, was "@import 'compass';")
```

The file is just the following.  It does not even contain any of my own code

```
@charset "UTF-8"
@import 'compass';
```

I know that people say this error occurs when [the `@import` line misses semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18517322/2841279), but my file has the semicolon.

And the same files (scss and config.rb) can be easily compiled in linux with no problems.

---

Does anybody know what is wrong?

The configuration which gives error is

```
Windows 8.1
ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [i386-mingw32]
Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
Sass 3.4.16 (Selective Steve)
```

I tried many combinations

```
(1)
-------------------
@import 'compass';    
-------------------
// only this line, no @charset line.
// Result: compilation ok, but I need charset because 
// my COMMENTS (yes only comments) have UTF8 chars.
```

---

```
(2)
-------------------
@charset "UTF-8";

@import 'compass';    
-------------------
// semicolon after @charset
// Result: compilation error:
// Invalid CP950 character "\xE2"
// because the @charset line is unrecognised
```

---

```
(3)
// Add this to config.rb
Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8'
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/23338595/2841279
// http://blog.pixelastic.com/2014/09/06/compass-utf-8-encoding-on-windows/
// Result: compilation error: expected selector or
// at-rule, was "@import 'compass';
```

---

```
(4)
// Add this to config.rb
encoding = "utf-8"
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/13987672/2841279
// Result: compilation error: expected selector or
// at-rule, was "@import 'compass';
```

Answer (score 10):

Looks like putting that anywhere other than the first line of the page results in that error. Try putting it right at the top and see if it fixes that issue.

Comment: Yep, come back to this answer twice and it's fixed it both times. If I could upvote again I would. Very annoying behaviour on the part of Laravel/Composer/Webpack/whatever's responsible to be constantly adding that line where it fails, seems like a bug that should not be present 6 months on.

Comment: @HashimAziz Hahahah... I had the same situation and if I could upvote this answer again I would. Yeah... Laravel behavior very annoying...

Answer (score 1):

`@charset "UTF-8";` is added by the compiler e.g. sass whenever required

Answer (score 1):

this is how it needs to be in order to work

```
@charset "UTF-8";@import 'compass';
```